# Do I need to buy return ticket when travelling on a long-stay visa?

Tags: schengen, tickets, residency

I have visa type D for Denmark which is valid for 180 days to collect my residence card type c. Do I need to buy return ticket or one way ticket is enough? I am asking because air travel agent is asking me to buy return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a return ticket, as long as you can show a proof (e.g., letter) that says come and collect your residency card; In case the staff ask you about the intent of your trip to Denmark.